# Create large number of Hyperlinks in Word with VBA

Tags: vba, hyperlink, ms-word

I have to create a large number (1000-5000) of hyperlinks in word with VBA. This procedure is necessary every time the document is started.  I'd like to speed up my code.

```
Sub CreateHyperlinks(raHypers() As Range, saSubaddresses() As String, saScreentips() As String)

Dim i As Integer

Application.Visible = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
    For i = 0 To UBound(raHypers)
        .Add raHypers(i), , saSubaddresses(i), saScreentips(i)
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

The array raHypers() is already sorted by the start property of the range variable in ascending order. I have already tried different things, but the code still takes quite long. Has anybody an idea how to speed it up?

Comment: Why on Earth would want to put 5000 links in  a *Word* document?  There are other types of documents *made for links*... and they are much easier to create.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a code optimization question

Answer (score 0):

did you tried a "for each" loop instead of your loop?

```
Sub CreateHyperlinks()

    Dim myHyperlink As Hyperlink

    For Each myHyperlink In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
        *your code*
    Next myHyperlink

End Sub
```

Edit1:

I missunderstood your question at 1st read, but you can use it nevertheless.
You just have to access the range of your hyperlinks with a "for each" loop instead of looping through it with an index.

This could speedup your code.

```
Sub CreateHyperlinks( _
    raHypers() As Range, _
    saSubaddresses() As String, _
    saScreentips() As String)

    Dim myRange As Range

    For Each myRange In raHypers
        ' your code
    Next myRange

End Sub
```

Edit:
Sry, i have no further ideas to speedup your code.